# How to add a class or id to a column in jqGrid

Tags: javascript, css, jqgrid

How do I add class or id in a column, actually I think this is the way I need to change the color of a "hover" in only one column, I tried some ways but failed.

```
jQuery(grid_selector).jqGrid({
  url:urllst,
  datatype: 'json',
  height: 'auto',
  width: 'auto',
  ignoreCase: true,
  colNames:['XX','XX','XX','XX','XX','XX','XX,'XX','XX','XX','XX?' ],  
  colModel:[
    {name:"XX",index:"XX", width:100, sorttype:'text', viewable: true, frozen: true, focus: true, 
      stype:'text',
      formoptions:{elmprefix:'*', label: 'XX:', rowpos:1, colpos:1},
      editable:true,
      editrules: {required: true},
      edittype: 'custom',
      editoptions: {style: "text-transform: uppercase",
      'custom_element' : macro_uf_element,
      'custom_value'   : macro_uf_value,
    },
```

It is very important whether it be by JavaScript if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell jqGrid to add a class to every cell of a column:

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options

> **Property**: classes 
>   **Description:** This option allow to add classes to the column. If more than one class will be used a space should be set. By example
>   classes:'class1 class2' will set a class1 and class2 to every cell on
>   that column. In the grid css there is a predefined class ui-ellipsis
>   which allow to attach ellipsis to a particular row. Also this will
>   work in FireFox too.

```
jQuery(grid_selector).jqGrid({
  url:urllst,
  datatype: 'json',
  height: 'auto',
  width: 'auto',
  ignoreCase: true,
  colNames:['XX','XX','XX','XX','XX','XX','XX','XX','XX','XX','XX?' ],  
  colModel:[
    {name:"XX",index:"XX", width:100, sorttype:'text', viewable: true, frozen: true,
   focus: true, 
   stype:'text',
   formoptions:{elmprefix:'*', label: 'XX:', rowpos:1, colpos:1},
   editable:true,
   editrules: {required: true},
   edittype: 'custom',
   editoptions: {style: "text-transform: uppercase",
   'custom_element' : macro_uf_element,
   'custom_value'   : macro_uf_value,
   classes: 'your_class_here'
},
```

Comment: OMG, man thankyou, i looked this page 2 times and not seen it.
So sorry!